# HTTP POST request and basic authentication

Tags: json, http, post, basic-authentication

When I do:

```
curl https://example.com/my/ressource \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"itemid":["123","456"]}' \
  -u myuser
```

I get HTTP 403 Forbidden error code. If I use a get request it works, e.g.

```
curl https://example.com/my/ressource
```

Works fine. Also if I disable basic authentication at the server side the above post request works fine.

The server is an Apache 2.4 and it is acting as a reverse proxy.

What is wrong with the post request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that in the above case Apache is used as a reverse proxy and the server behind Apache could not handle Authorization, so the solution was to remove this header with:

```
RequestHeader unset Authorization
```